# Configure Boot Menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot, boot.ini, boot-manager

I Have Two Hard Disk Drive.In One Hard Disk Installed Windows Xp And In Other Hard Disk Installed Windows 7.I Want Install Two Hard Disk in One System And Configure This System For Boot Menu with Windows Xp And Windows 7.

How can I Configure Boot Menu To Show with Two Choose (Windows Xp And Windows 7).Please Help me for This

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to combine two OSes in one hard disk and be able to multi-boot from that disc. This requires partition move if you don't want to reinstall one of the OSes.  You can use 3rd party programs like [BootIt™ Next Generation](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-next-generation.htm) which can do all the copying/sliding/resizing/imaging and any other partition work you ever need, and it includes its own bootloader which can boot any OS. It also allows you to easily boot multiple OSes from a single partition.

As for an alternative solution, you can format one of the drives (let's say Drive D with Windows 7) and then reinstall that OS to Drive C for multi-booting. [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5126781/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-with-xp-or-vista) has a nice article explaining how to dual boot Windows 7 with XP.